# What's behind these memory card problems with my new Nikon D7000?

Tags: troubleshooting, memory-card, body, nikon-d7000, error

Recently I bought Nikon D-7000. It's fantastic camera, but I am facing few problems:

1. I am using 16GB San Disk memory card in slot 1. While taking photos, sometimes it shows a memory card error. If I turn off and turn on the camera it functions normally. But sometimes it happens again. Is this because of a defect in the camera or might it be because of the memory card?
2. Sometimes when there is error showing about the memory card, when I turn off the camera, the control panel light continues to glow with the details. At that time I need to remove the battery. Why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried another card?  Or tried the same card in the other card slot (if possible)?  Trying another card would help determine if it's the card or the camera.  Also, have you tried reformatting the card?  I can only guess that when the camera CP light stays on when you switch off the camera, it's because the camera is still trying to communicate with the card (to transfer an image or whatever).

Comment: @MikeW: I haven't tried in another slot. Will make a try and check how it goes. So as you mentioned, camera is trying to communicate with the card - so could be a card issue?
I am afraid, should not be a camera issue.
Thanks. Will check and update.

Comment: I have tried another card and it has the same problem. (Though the cards are identical in make and model.)

Comment: I have the same problem on my D7000

Comment: @jsquare: When did you bought that? Any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have the one camera and one card, it's going to be hard to determine which is the problem.  As commenters have suggested, the easiest way to troubleshoot such a situation is to:

- try the memory card in another camera
- try another memory card in this camera

With respect to the "control panel light" staying on, I'm not sure what you mean by "control panel light".  If you mean the little light that lights up when the camera is accessing the memory card, it could be related to your memory card troubles.  If you mean the big color screen on the back of the camera, or the LCD display on top of the camera (that shows shutter speed, aperture, etc), and those are staying on when the camera is in the "off" position, then there is definitely a problem with the camera.  The color screen on the back of the camera should be off when the camera is off.  The LCD display on top of the camera should be off as well, with the exception of showing the number of photos (estimated) that can be stored on the free space of the memory card.

Comment: Thanks will check with different card and also memory card in another camera.
Yes, I mean the LCD on the top. As Mike mentioned, camera may try to communicate with memory card. I am yet to checkout these. Will check and update.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my D5100, but it was easily resolved with a firmware update. For my D5100, the installed firmware was a:1.00 and b:1.00. The update was to a:1.01 b:1.01. I did a quick search and found [this support post regarding the D7000 firmware version a:1.02/b:1.03](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17542/~/d7000-firmware:-a:-1.0.2-/-b:1.03-upgrade). One of the modifications:

> An error where the card may not have been recognized when some memory cards were used has been addressed.

The description in the D5100 firmware update was very similar, and it resolved my issues. If it's the same thing affecting your D7000, I would suggest updating the firmware.

Comment: But this is new a camera got a month ago, does this require a firmware update?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you bought it, it's the manufacture date that's important.

Answer (score 1):

Do a firmware update to 1.0.3. It fixed my problem; it's been weeks since I've seen a card error.

It's available [here on Nikon USA](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17542).

Comment: Cool, how did you do that from downloaded from Nikon website?

Comment: @shankar: Yes; I've edited my answer to include the link.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Sometimes when there is error showing about the memory card, when I
>   turn off the camera, the control panel light continues to glow with
>   the details. At that time I need to remove the battery. Why this is
>   happening?

This sounds like normal functionality for the D7000. Even when the camera is turned off, the top LCD panel will continue to display the number of shots remaining on your memory card (or an error if no memory card is found).

Comment: Is it, I am not aware of that functionality, exploring on.. Yes when camera is turned off the LCD displays number of slots or 1.6k something like that. But sometimes when the memory card is present and it shows no mem. card present - at that time the LCD panel displays everything like ISO detail, AF and others, also the light is glowing (if turned on before).

Comment: I want to clarify and say that this is indeed not the normal functionality. Normally, the camera goes into a "soft-off" mode displaying only the card icons and the number of potential shots left. The problem OP describes can be identified by a fully operational, *stuck* LCD screen. Everything from AF points to WB status is there. Replacing the battery seems to remedy the condition, as does, IIRC, making a USB connection before turning the camera off. In any case, it's very annoying.